# Why Total Amount Calculates On One Row Only

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Sorry, this is just a simple problem. The problem is that the total amount is only calculating one row. It calculates only one row of a specific product that is clicked. So, how to calculate the whole total amount from all rows?

```js
const cart = {};
let GrandTotal = 0;

function AddtoCart(productid, description, quantity, price) {
  if (cart[productid]) {
    cart[productid].qty += quantity;
  } else {
    cart[productid] = {
      id: productid,
      desc: description,
      qty: quantity,
      price: price
    };
  }
  
  viewCart();
  
  
  GrandTotal += parseFloat(cart[productid].price) * parseInt(cart[productid].qty);  
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = GrandTotal;
  console.log(GrandTotal);
  
  }

function viewCart() {
  let tbody = document.getElementById('cartsBody');
  tbody.innerHTML = '';
  Object.values(cart).forEach(content => {
    tbody.innerHTML += `<td>${ content.id }</td>
                      <td>${ content.desc }</td>
                      <td>${ content.qty }</td>
                      <td>${ content.price }</td>
                      <td>${ content.qty * content.price }</td>`;


  });
 
}
```

```html
<script src="script.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="Laptop" onclick="AddtoCart('132','Macbook Pro', 1, 79000,0)" />
<input type="button" value="Phone" onclick="AddtoCart('456','Iphone 5S', 1, 18000,0)" />
<input type="button" value="Camera" onclick="AddtoCart('789','Nikon 3D00', 1, 25000,0)" />

<table border="1|1" id="cartsTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product ID</th>
      <th>Product Description</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="cartsBody">
  </tbody>
</table>
<p id="total">Total: </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recalculate grand total from the cart data every time, instead of trying to add to it whenever you click on a product. You might also want to remove items later on.

```
function calculateGrandTotal(){
    GrandTotal = 0;
    for(let productid in cart){
        if(cart.hasOwnProperty(productid)){
            GrandTotal += parseFloat(cart[productid].price) * parseInt(cart[productid].qty);
        }
    }
}
```

And in your `AddToCart` function you just call the calculate function:

```
function AddtoCart(productid, description, quantity, price) {
    // [...]
    calculateGrandTotal();
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = GrandTotal;
    console.log(GrandTotal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time addToCart is clicked, you set grandtotal to zero.

Initialize your grandtotal variable outside the click function.

Comment: You always add the total of all products of the chosen type to grand total, instead of just the one added. Example: you already have 1 camera in the cart. If you add another camera, it will add the price for 2 cameras to grand total instead of one.

Comment: @Danmoreng. So how will i fix this? I know the logic but can't write it in code